# How to fix a connection issue with my C++ Client?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, connection, winsock2

Everytime when I've tried to use my client to connect to the server on port 2997, it simply didn't work. Nothing happens, no message confirming and no error message. I executed the client as Admin on my Windows 11.
And when look into the Tasks Manager, my client stays at 0% CPU usage. This is the client's code:

```
// Client side C/C++ program to demonstrate Socket
// programming
#include <Winsock2.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

#define PORT 2997

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{

 int status, valread, client_fd;
 struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
 char* hello = "Hello from client";
 char buffer[1024] = { 0 };

 WSAData data;
 WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
 int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &data);
 if(wsResult != 0){
    std::cerr << "Can't start sour cnin" << wsResult << std::endl;
 }

 if ((client_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
    printf("\n Socket creation error \n");
    return -1;
 }

 serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

 // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary
 // form
 if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.100.43", &serv_addr.sin_addr)
    <= 0) {
    printf(
        "\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n");
    return -1;
 }

 if ((status
     = connect(client_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,
               sizeof(serv_addr)))
    < 0) {
    printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
    return -1;
 }
 send(client_fd, hello, strlen(hello), 0);
 printf("Hello message sent\n");
 valread = read(client_fd, buffer, 1024);
 printf("%s\n", buffer);

 // closing the connected socket
 close(client_fd);
 return 0;
}
```

I don't know what to do.
Somebody thinks that I have to enable Remote Desktop inside Control Panel or is it caused by another problem?

Comment: Check what `send` returns. And check what happens on the other side of the connection.

Comment: Also, in Windows you must use `recv` to receive data, not `read`. And you need to check what it returns as well. Also, will the sender really send a null.terminated string? AGain, check what `recv` returns, and if positive then use it to set the null-terminator in the received data.

Comment: Similarly with `close`, on Windows you need to use `closesocket`. It seems you're mixing Windows and non-Windows systems when writing your program.

Comment: In addition to what's already been said, I would use a tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [tcpdump](https://www.tcpdump.org/) to see what's actually going on "on the wire".

Comment: See also [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) and [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)...

Comment: Additionally, if this was on a more developer-friendly Linux platform, one could easily run the whole thing under `strace` and observe the running program actually making, or not making, each system call, and see exactly what it's doing. I never heard of a comparable diagnostic tool on MS-Windows.

Comment: On another couple of notes... If `WSAStartup` fails, you should not continue, And you should return a small *positive* value from `main` if the program "fail" (there's always `EXIT_FAILURE` defined for you). And if any function fails, you should report *why* it failed. Print `errno` (or use `strerror(errno)` on non-Windows systems, `WSAGetLastError()` on Windows). And your code is indeed a mix of different operating systems: The `<unistd.h>` is a POSIX (Unix, Linux, macOS) header file, Windows should not have it.

Comment: [Continued] And please don't mix C with your C++ code. Use `std::string` for strings. `char* hello = "Hello from client";` is actually *invalid* in C++. The `struct` keyword is not needed when declaring structure objects. And why are you using `printf` to print output instead of `std::cout` (or `std::cerr` as you use for one single case)? You seem to mix and match not only your operating systems, but also your languages.

Comment: Side note use ports in the 49152 – 65535 range they should be free to use. But always check on your systems that the port number is not already in use.

Comment: @PepijnKramer if the port were in use or otherwise prohibited, there would be an error reported.

Comment: @CésarEspíndola what is the ACTUAL problem you are having? Please be more specific. I don't see a single condition in this code would cause all of the symptoms you have described. Even if the client were blocked on `connect()` or `read()`, there would still be at least 1 message output beforehand. Have you stepped through the code with a debugger to see what is really happening? What does your server code look like?

Answer (score 0):

I used **recv()**, i deactived my antivirus and firewall. But nothing worked. I also used Wireshark and the only things it shows it is my ip address and the ip address of the destination, but no signal or datagram or something that proves some connection was made.

One strange thing i must inform all of you, it is that if i execute the server and the client socket on my Ubuntu machine, it works. But it's just a localhost connection(127.0.0.1) or my lan ip( 192.168.0.***). But when i try to Establish a connection using the server and client socket on the same Windows machine or when i try between two different machines on my lan or between my computer and an external machine(an IP address outside), nothing happens.